# why does the error originate from a subprocess. s it because of low internet, or failure will the collecting setuptools?

Tags: installation, pip, upgrade, chatterbot

I keep getting an error when i am downloading chatterbot, but it says the error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. Please help me?

I thought it was going to download the latest version of chatterbot, since i updated it